# Web Scraping Extract Javascript Table Selenium+Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've read several articles of Web Scraping with but I didn't undestand how to find the elements in the site.

The site I want to scrap the table is below:
http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/cotacoes/mercado-de-derivativos/?symbol=DI1

I want to scrap the tables: "TB01, "TB02, TB03 and TB04" theses are the ids of the tables

```
<tbody> == $0
  <tr>
    <td id="TB01">...</td>
    <td id="TB02">...</td>
    <td id="TB03">...</td>
    <td id="TB04">...</td>
  <tr>
```

I've tried all the `find.element` functions of the Selenium libraries but none of then works.

Also the site has some load to wait, I've used to the function `WebDriverWait` but it should be tie with the presence of the table, if the `find_element` didn't work probably the `WebDriverWait` neither I guess.

Comment: Could you include the rest of your attempted code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple if you analyze the website and it's working in the backend via chrome developer tools.

Before diving into scraping you need to know about ajax requests in the web. Most websites use ajax requests, therefore, everything is loaded dynamically.

Steps to follow:

1. Open the website in a new tab in chrome
2. Open the developer console of chrome
3. Go to Network tab and refresh the page. You can see the calls being by the website as it is loaded dynamically.

For the website - http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/cotacoes/mercado-de-derivativos/?symbol=DI1 ,here's the image.

[image]

You can see the DL1 API being called. Go to the headers and see the url.
Now you get to know the url. Therefore, it's very easy to get the data using python. Here's the code.

```
import requests, json
text = reuqests.get("http://cotacao.b3.com.br/mds/api/v1/DerivativeQuotation/DI1").text
data = json.loads(text)
print(data['Scty'])
```

The output of the above program will be as follows

```
[{'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 7.7862,
   'bottomLmtPric': 7.01,
   'curPrc': 7.78,
   'maxPric': 7.79,
   'minPric': 7.74,
   'opngPric': 7.74,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 7.684,
   'topLmtPric': 8.525},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 111008714.5,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-06-03',
    'opnCtrcts': 36655,
    'tradQty': 141,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 1175},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 7.64},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 7.675},
  'symb': 'DI1M19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 8.1758,
   'bottomLmtPric': 7.49,
   'curPrc': 8.19,
   'maxPric': 8.3,
   'minPric': 8.13,
   'opngPric': 8.21,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 8.237,
   'topLmtPric': 9.2},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 417475320.0,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-10-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 769684,
    'tradQty': 167,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 4550},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 8.16},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 8.19},
  'symb': 'DI1V19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 6.6549,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.125,
   'curPrc': 6.7,
   'maxPric': 6.71,
   'minPric': 6.645,
   'opngPric': 6.68,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 6.669,
   'topLmtPric': 7.235},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 245262515.35,
    'mtrtyCode': '2018-12-03',
    'opnCtrcts': 193484,
    'tradQty': 26,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 2495},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 6.68},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 6.695},
  'symb': 'DI1Z18'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 12.4511,
   'bottomLmtPric': 11.58,
   'curPrc': 12.4,
   'maxPric': 12.63,
   'minPric': 12.39,
   'opngPric': 12.45,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.533,
   'topLmtPric': 13.78},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 995856709.26,
    'mtrtyCode': '2027-01-04',
    'opnCtrcts': 339175,
    'tradQty': 2616,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 26466},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 12.39},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 12.4},
  'symb': 'DI1F27'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 10.542,
   'bottomLmtPric': 9.61,
   'curPrc': 10.6,
   'maxPric': 10.6,
   'minPric': 10.4,
   'opngPric': 10.43,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 10.525,
   'topLmtPric': 11.71},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 3667893.9,
    'mtrtyCode': '2021-10-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 25005,
    'tradQty': 10,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 50},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 10.42},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 10.44},
  'symb': 'DI1V21'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'bottomLmtPric': 11.5,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.445,
   'topLmtPric': 13.69},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'mtrtyCode': '2026-07-01', 'opnCtrcts': 3325},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'symb': 'DI1N26'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 8.8308,
   'bottomLmtPric': 8.08,
   'curPrc': 8.83,
   'maxPric': 9,
   'minPric': 8.78,
   'opngPric': 8.86,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 8.886,
   'topLmtPric': 9.94},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 355167456.9,
    'mtrtyCode': '2020-04-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 647478,
    'tradQty': 269,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 4065},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 8.82},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 8.83},
  'symb': 'DI1J20'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 7.6,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.86,
   'curPrc': 7.6,
   'maxPric': 7.6,
   'minPric': 7.6,
   'opngPric': 7.6,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 7.515,
   'topLmtPric': 8.325},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 476031.4,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-05-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 47300,
    'tradQty': 1,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 5},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 7.46},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 7.5},
  'symb': 'DI1K19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 10.6572,
   'bottomLmtPric': 9.77,
   'curPrc': 10.62,
   'maxPric': 10.81,
   'minPric': 10.57,
   'opngPric': 10.6,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 10.695,
   'topLmtPric': 11.88},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 2389488485.5,
    'mtrtyCode': '2022-01-03',
    'opnCtrcts': 744332,
    'tradQty': 3539,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 33516},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 10.61},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 10.63},
  'symb': 'DI1F22'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 6.8224,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.26,
   'curPrc': 6.83,
   'maxPric': 6.88,
   'minPric': 6.78,
   'opngPric': 6.8,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 6.835,
   'topLmtPric': 7.47},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 3759849797.05,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-01-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 3296622,
    'tradQty': 1187,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 38465},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 6.825},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 6.835},
  'symb': 'DI1F19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 12.6441,
   'bottomLmtPric': 11.8,
   'curPrc': 12.6,
   'maxPric': 12.84,
   'minPric': 12.6,
   'opngPric': 12.67,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.753,
   'topLmtPric': 14},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 305050246.35,
    'mtrtyCode': '2029-01-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 87547,
    'tradQty': 807,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 10415},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 12.59},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 12.6},
  'symb': 'DI1F29'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 7.185,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.57,
   'curPrc': 7.185,
   'maxPric': 7.185,
   'minPric': 7.185,
   'opngPric': 7.185,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 7.196,
   'topLmtPric': 7.93},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 965104.3,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-03-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 42941,
    'tradQty': 1,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 10},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 7.185},
  'symb': 'DI1H19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'bottomLmtPric': 11.29,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.236,
   'topLmtPric': 13.47},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'mtrtyCode': '2025-07-01', 'opnCtrcts': 3485},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'symb': 'DI1N25'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 9.6967,
   'bottomLmtPric': 8.89,
   'curPrc': 9.68,
   'maxPric': 9.85,
   'minPric': 9.63,
   'opngPric': 9.7,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 9.766,
   'topLmtPric': 10.9},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 14461876431.2,
    'mtrtyCode': '2021-01-04',
    'opnCtrcts': 1589400,
    'tradQty': 11304,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 179775},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 9.67},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 9.68},
  'symb': 'DI1F21'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 9.1373,
   'bottomLmtPric': 8.35,
   'curPrc': 9.13,
   'maxPric': 9.29,
   'minPric': 9.08,
   'opngPric': 9.1,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 9.186,
   'topLmtPric': 10.28},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 1676360397.45,
    'mtrtyCode': '2020-07-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 1438827,
    'tradQty': 2742,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 19685},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 9.12},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 9.13},
  'symb': 'DI1N20'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 10.8811,
   'bottomLmtPric': 9.96,
   'curPrc': 10.97,
   'maxPric': 10.97,
   'minPric': 10.78,
   'opngPric': 10.78,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 10.885,
   'topLmtPric': 12.08},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 3106685.3,
    'mtrtyCode': '2022-04-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 16160,
    'tradQty': 7,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 45},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 10.78},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 10.81},
  'symb': 'DI1J22'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 11.7735,
   'bottomLmtPric': 10.89,
   'curPrc': 11.7,
   'maxPric': 11.91,
   'minPric': 11.69,
   'opngPric': 11.74,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 11.836,
   'topLmtPric': 13.06},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 88173754.85,
    'mtrtyCode': '2024-01-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 63830,
    'tradQty': 247,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 1595},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 11.69},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 11.71},
  'symb': 'DI1F24'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 10.0743,
   'bottomLmtPric': 9.1,
   'curPrc': 10.08,
   'maxPric': 10.08,
   'minPric': 10.07,
   'opngPric': 10.07,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 9.996,
   'topLmtPric': 11.15},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 2730323.55,
    'mtrtyCode': '2021-04-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 57813,
    'tradQty': 5,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 35},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 9.92},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 9.94},
  'symb': 'DI1J21'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 11.3251,
   'bottomLmtPric': 10.43,
   'curPrc': 11.29,
   'maxPric': 11.49,
   'minPric': 11.24,
   'opngPric': 11.27,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 11.375,
   'topLmtPric': 12.59},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 2902365222.1,
    'mtrtyCode': '2023-01-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 643495,
    'tradQty': 5563,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 46221},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 11.28},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 11.29},
  'symb': 'DI1F23'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'bottomLmtPric': 6.043,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 6.394,
   'topLmtPric': 6.743},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'mtrtyCode': '2018-09-03', 'opnCtrcts': 794385},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 6.391},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 6.394},
  'symb': 'DI1U18'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 10.9889,
   'bottomLmtPric': 10.12,
   'curPrc': 10.98,
   'maxPric': 11.18,
   'minPric': 10.96,
   'opngPric': 11.01,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 11.055,
   'topLmtPric': 12.25},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 751347046.85,
    'mtrtyCode': '2022-07-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 107601,
    'tradQty': 378,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 11210},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 10.98},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 10.99},
  'symb': 'DI1N22'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 6.525,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.025,
   'curPrc': 6.525,
   'maxPric': 6.525,
   'minPric': 6.525,
   'opngPric': 6.525,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 6.528,
   'topLmtPric': 7.025},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 49414005.0,
    'mtrtyCode': '2018-11-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 388520,
    'tradQty': 8,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 500},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 6.51},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 6.56},
  'symb': 'DI1X18'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 7.3144,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.695,
   'curPrc': 7.32,
   'maxPric': 7.41,
   'minPric': 7.26,
   'opngPric': 7.28,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 7.341,
   'topLmtPric': 8.115},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 2331794391.85,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-04-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 818987,
    'tradQty': 391,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 24305},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 7.315},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 7.325},
  'symb': 'DI1J19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 6.4435,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.015,
   'curPrc': 6.448,
   'maxPric': 6.45,
   'minPric': 6.435,
   'opngPric': 6.45,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 6.447,
   'topLmtPric': 6.875},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 6047420821.25,
    'mtrtyCode': '2018-10-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 2472721,
    'tradQty': 133,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 60850},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 6.446},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 6.448},
  'symb': 'DI1V18'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 12.2392,
   'bottomLmtPric': 11.39,
   'curPrc': 12.2,
   'maxPric': 12.41,
   'minPric': 12.2,
   'opngPric': 12.26,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.334,
   'topLmtPric': 13.57},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 13930258.0,
    'mtrtyCode': '2026-01-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 78158,
    'tradQty': 40,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 325},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 12.19},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 12.21},
  'symb': 'DI1F26'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 9.439,
   'bottomLmtPric': 8.64,
   'curPrc': 9.51,
   'maxPric': 9.57,
   'minPric': 9.4,
   'opngPric': 9.4,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 9.496,
   'topLmtPric': 10.61},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 1046752634.45,
    'mtrtyCode': '2020-10-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 219310,
    'tradQty': 62,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 12645},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 9.41},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 9.44},
  'symb': 'DI1V20'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'bottomLmtPric': 10.56,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 11.509,
   'topLmtPric': 12.72},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'mtrtyCode': '2023-04-03', 'opnCtrcts': 11610},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'symb': 'DI1J23'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 10.2088,
   'bottomLmtPric': 9.37,
   'curPrc': 10.18,
   'maxPric': 10.35,
   'minPric': 10.14,
   'opngPric': 10.14,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 10.276,
   'topLmtPric': 11.45},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 1141539998.05,
    'mtrtyCode': '2021-07-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 407600,
    'tradQty': 989,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 15035},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 10.17},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 10.18},
  'symb': 'DI1N21'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 7.0568,
   'bottomLmtPric': 6.405,
   'curPrc': 7.02,
   'maxPric': 7.065,
   'minPric': 7.02,
   'opngPric': 7.065,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 7.01,
   'topLmtPric': 7.7},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 22816998.75,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-02-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 198230,
    'tradQty': 29,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 235},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 6.99},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 7.02},
  'symb': 'DI1G19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 7.7849,
   'bottomLmtPric': 7.12,
   'curPrc': 7.775,
   'maxPric': 7.9,
   'minPric': 7.715,
   'opngPric': 7.73,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 7.817,
   'topLmtPric': 8.7},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 3488606085.5,
    'mtrtyCode': '2019-07-01',
    'opnCtrcts': 791673,
    'tradQty': 1523,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 37135},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 7.77},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 7.78},
  'symb': 'DI1N19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 12.0531,
   'bottomLmtPric': 11.16,
   'curPrc': 12.01,
   'maxPric': 12.23,
   'minPric': 11.99,
   'opngPric': 12.03,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.114,
   'topLmtPric': 13.35},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 1748133912.1,
    'mtrtyCode': '2025-01-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 525980,
    'tradQty': 3842,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 35941},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 12},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 12.01},
  'symb': 'DI1F25'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 12.725,
   'bottomLmtPric': 11.71,
   'curPrc': 12.73,
   'maxPric': 12.73,
   'minPric': 12.72,
   'opngPric': 12.72,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.658,
   'topLmtPric': 13.9},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 327258.25,
    'mtrtyCode': '2028-01-03',
    'opnCtrcts': 9805,
    'tradQty': 2,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 10},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 12.47},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 12.51},
  'symb': 'DI1F28'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 8.5217,
   'bottomLmtPric': 7.8,
   'curPrc': 8.51,
   'maxPric': 8.66,
   'minPric': 8.46,
   'opngPric': 8.51,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 8.576,
   'topLmtPric': 9.59},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 12632820547.85,
    'mtrtyCode': '2020-01-02',
    'opnCtrcts': 2512243,
    'tradQty': 7202,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 141065},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 8.51},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 8.52},
  'symb': 'DI1F20'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'bottomLmtPric': 11.84,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 12.79,
   'topLmtPric': 14.03},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'mtrtyCode': '2030-01-02', 'opnCtrcts': 5325},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'symb': 'DI1F30'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'bottomLmtPric': 11.04,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 11.991,
   'topLmtPric': 13.21},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'mtrtyCode': '2024-07-01', 'opnCtrcts': 25060},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 11.83},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 11.87},
  'symb': 'DI1N24'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'bottomLmtPric': 7.27,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 7.974,
   'topLmtPric': 8.895},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'mtrtyCode': '2019-08-01', 'opnCtrcts': 24280},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 7.905},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 7.94},
  'symb': 'DI1Q19'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 11.292,
   'bottomLmtPric': 10.28,
   'curPrc': 11.3,
   'maxPric': 11.3,
   'minPric': 11.29,
   'opngPric': 11.29,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 11.22,
   'topLmtPric': 12.42},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 1613776.85,
    'mtrtyCode': '2022-10-03',
    'opnCtrcts': 32880,
    'tradQty': 3,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 25},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 11.1},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 11.13},
  'symb': 'DI1V22'},
 {'SctyQtn': {'avrgPric': 11.5762,
   'bottomLmtPric': 10.65,
   'curPrc': 11.5,
   'maxPric': 11.68,
   'minPric': 11.5,
   'opngPric': 11.58,
   'prvsDayAdjstmntPric': 11.602,
   'topLmtPric': 12.82},
  'asset': {'AsstSummry': {'grssAmt': 19148925.5,
    'mtrtyCode': '2023-07-03',
    'opnCtrcts': 22610,
    'tradQty': 29,
    'traddCtrctsQty': 325},
   'code': 'DI1'},
  'buyOffer': {'price': 11.5},
  'mkt': {'cd': 'FUT'},
  'sellOffer': {'price': 11.51},
  'symb': 'DI1N23'}]
```

Comment: awesome answer, its turn my life so much easier, I've also tried in another site and it follows the same pattern there is a call in an API. Thank you so much